# Azure Databricks pricing: B2B subscription vs official page pricing

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

From one company I know that 50,000 DBUs for B2B Non-Production subscription may cost about 44,000$. In turn, [at Databricks official pricing page](https://databricks.com/product/azure-pricing), the most premium layer costs 0.55$/DBU (27,500$ per 50k DBUs).

*Could you please explain the difference between B2B subscription DBUs and official page Data Analytics Pemium SKU DBUs?*

Why the pricing differs so dramatically? Is there anything else (as part of B2B) besides support/fastrack?

Hope you won't need to publish private informationto to answer my question. But I need to understand the main reasons, to be able to plan costs for future projects.

### UPD

Databricks B2B subscription *does not* provide you with a choice of different usage layers (Light/Engineering/Analytics). Instead you have a single option (price) for each bundle (DBU volume). That option is significantly more expensive than the most expensive Analytics layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it as getting a discount on $50,000 worth of tokens. The way you run your process will pull from that bucket as if you had $50,000 to spend even though you are paying $46,000.  You have a year or 3 years to spend them, if you don't spend them in that timeframe you lose the remaining.  If you go through them all you will pay the pay-as-you-go price or you can pre-buy another year or 3 year bucket of units.  Also how you run your jobs and what tier you run under (Standard or Premium) will determine how fast you burn through the bucket of units and does still matter as the previous answer stated.

```
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/databricks/
```

> **Databricks Unit pre-purchase plan**
>
> You can get up to 37% savings over pay-as-you-go DBU prices when you
> pre-purchase Azure Databricks Units (DBU) as Databricks Commit Units
> (DBCU) for either 1 or 3 years. A Databricks Commit Unit (DBCU)
> normalizes usage from Azure Databricks workloads and tiers into to a
> single purchase. Your DBU usage across those workloads and tiers will
> draw down from the Databricks Commit Units (DBCU) until they are
> exhausted, or the purchase term expires. The draw down rate will be
> equivalent to the price of the DBU, as per the table above.
>
> The purchase tiers and discounts for DBCU purchases are shown below:
>
> **1-year pre-purchase plan**
>
> DATABRICKS COMMIT UNIT (DBCU) PRICE (WITH DISCOUNT)   DISCOUNT
>
> 25,000                                  $23,500             6%
>
> 50,000                                  $46,000             8%
>
> 100,000                                 $89,000            11%
>
> 200,000                                 $172,000           14%
>
> 350,000                                 $287,000           18%
>
> 500,000                                 $400,000           20%
>
> 750,000                                 $578,000           22%
>
> 1,000,000                               $730,000           27%
>
> 1,500,000                               $1,050,000         30%
>
> 2,000,000                               $1,340,000         33%

Also Analytics/Engineering/Light are not options that you choose from.  They are defined by how you run your jobs.  Executing a job through the notebook interface is defined as an Analytics job where as if you schedule the notebook to run that is considered an engineering job and if you use a coded library submit job you are running under the light tier.

UPDATE - not enough room in comment section to answer OP reply

great thanks for your answer! I think I got my mistake, but please approve once again. So DBCU is about US dollars, so 50k DCBUs may be equal to let say ~100k DBUs, right?

DBUs and DBCUs are exactly the same and are charged the same as far as usage. The only difference is that you get an up front discount of 8% with your example of pre buying 50,000. If you were to run everything exactly the same in two different workspaces and you spent exactly 50,000 DBU Hours in one and 50,000 DBCU Hours in the other, you would owe $50,000 over the course of the year or you would pay $46,000 up front.  Neither of these include the actual VM base costs that you would owe to Azure. The DBU structure is Databricks cut of the cost, so you would have to factor that in to your overall cost.

This took me a while to figure out when I started with databricks as well.  When they say you are charged $0.55 for the Analytical job that is per DBU hour that is processed not .55 per job.  So if I run an Analytical job for 1 hour I would burn  .55 * (# of VM's * VM DBU cost per hour). If I ran that same job for only 1/2 an hour I would be charged (.55*.5) * (# of VM's * (VM DBU cost*.5)).  It's easier to think of the DBU and DBCU units as 1 unit = $1 and you are burning the dollar value per second of compute not the unit count.  The pricing grid that shows $0.55/DBU should be labeled $0.55/DBU-hour in my opinion. Took me a long time, a couple calls and a poc, to figure out.

As to your second question

And scheduling jobs through REST API is more beneficial then scheduling through ADF => Notebook, right?

Again the question is more complicated that it seems like it should be.  I initially said yes it is better, I didn't catch the ADF portion of the question.  You can run engineering jobs through ADF by making use of the job cluster option to run your notebooks.  If you attach your notebooks through ADF to a premade analytics cluster you will pay the analytics cost.  Using the API's you could schedule your notebooks in the built in jobscheduler that databricks provides.  My understanding is that is charged at the engineer level of a Notebook and light level if a job library.

Another thing to ask for when prebuying if you go that route is to be able to attach the bucket of units to both your dev/test environment and prod environment.  We keep them completely separate networks so we have two workspaces. can both pull from the same pool of units.  Depends on your azure setup. We went through Databricks sales when we set ours up but Microsoft should be able to do the same.

Comment: great thanks for your answer! I think I got my mistake, but please approve once again. So DBCU is about US dollars, so 50k DCBUs may be equal to let say ~100k DBUs, right? And scheduling jobs through REST API is more beneficial then scheduling through ADF => Notebook, right?

Comment: @VB_ I added more information to address your additional questions.  Hopefully that clears it up for you.  The pricing model is definitely very confusing.

Comment: thanks! As far as I understood, I'm purchasing DBUs with US dollars, that's why 1 DBU = 1$. I'm spending DBUs/dollars by the following formula: `<compute type rate> * <VM DBU cost> * <# of VMs> * <% of hour>`.

Comment: I think it's easy to proof this with Databricks price calculator https://databricks.com/product/aws-pricing/instance-types. It shows me that Databricks Standard SKU Light price is almost equal to EMR price. Databricks Standard SKU Light has the same functionality as EMR, while can be easily extended with extra features/costs

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the type of workload your cluster runs, you will either be charged for Data Engineering or Data Analytics workload.

For example, if the cluster runs workloads triggered by the Databricks jobs scheduler, you will be charged for the Data Engineering workload. If your cluster runs interactive features such as ad-hoc commands, you will be billed for Data Analytics workload.

> Here is an example on how billing works?

1. If you run Premium tier cluster for 100 hours in East US 2 with 10 DS13v2 instances, the billing would be the following for Data Analytics workload:

   - VM cost for 10 DS13v2 instances —100 hours x 10 instances x $0.598/hour = $598
   - DBU cost for Data Analytics workload for 10 DS13v2 instances —100 hours x 10 instances x 2 DBU per node x $0.55/DBU = $1,100
   - The total cost would therefore be $598 (VM Cost) + $1,100 (DBU Cost) = $1,698.

> In addition to **VM and DBU charges**, you may also be **charged** for **managed disks**, **public IP address** or any other resource such as **Azure Storage**, **Azure Cosmos DB** depending on your application.

**Still you have confusion on understanding the Azure Databricks pricing?**

I would suggest you to a create a billing support ticket to get more clarity on the "Azure Databricks pricing: B2B subscription vs official page pricing" which you are looking for.

**Step1:** Go to “Help+Support”

**Step2:** Under support =>Select + New support request

**Step3:** Fill Basic details: Issue type*: Billing

**Step4:** Review + Create

[image]

> **Note:** Azure provides **unlimited support** for subscription management, which includes **billing**, quota adjustments, and account transfers.

**Reference:** [How to create an Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request)

Comment: this question is about pre-purchased 50,000 DBUs. AFAIK, after pre-purchasing, it doesn't matter in which way you're submitting jobs. Sorry, I still not following how your answer address my question.

Comment: Also Azure support may also cost some money

Comment: Azure provides unlimited support for subscription management, which includes billing, quota adjustments, and account transfers.

Comment: so is your answer about "go and ask Azure?"

Comment: This kind of question are better to clarify the details via billing ticket. I would suggest to create a billing support ticket, so that the support engineers can explain you in detail  "why it charged cost about 44,000$". - Hope this helps.

Comment: I hope they have public policy regarding pricing they can share with community

Comment: Yes, we have public policy regarding the pricing. To answer you question, we need to go through the cost analysis report and analyze "why it charged cost about 44,000$". Thats the reason I'm asking you to create a billing support ticket. Which is completely at FREE of cost.

Comment: things are more simple. Currently the only option to pre-purchase 50,000 DBUs in Northern Europe is to pay 43,000$. You can't switch between different options or usage layers. Nothing to analyze. The question is - why 50k DBUs cost 43k$. I don't need company specific reasoning, I need a general rule for all. Do you want a screen attached with 50k DBU bundle pricing?